# jQuery - Alternar background-image de um elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho um elemento figure com uma série de imagens dentro:

```
<figure class="MiniModImgSlider">
  <img src="img01.jpg" alt="img01">
  <img src="img02.jpg" alt="img02">
  <img src="img03.jpg" alt="img03">
  <img src="img04.jpg" alt="img04">
  <img src="img05.jpg" alt="img05">
</figure>
```

Obs: As imagens estão com display:none.

Quero recuperar o caminho de cada imagem e atribuir ao background do elemento figure a cada 3 segundos. Para isso fiz esse script:

```
var imgs = $(".MiniModImgSlider img").map(function() 
{
  return $(this).attr('src');
});

for (var i = 0; i <= imgs.length; i++) 
{
  setInterval(function()
  {
    $(".MiniModImgSlider").css('background-image', 'url('+imgs[i]+')');
  },1000);
}
```

Só que ao invés de atribuir o caminho da imagem o script retorna undefined!
Como posso resolver isso?

[Código no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGMhG/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um problema é que você está definindo vários `setInterval`, um para cada imagem, o que faz com que existam um monte de timers concorrendo para fazer alteração da imagem sendo exibida.

Você não precisa de um `for`, mas sim, somente de um `setInterval` com uma variável de controle definida em algum lugar, de forma a saber qual é a próxima imagem a ser exibida.

### [Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4rm7/)

```
var imgs = $(".MiniModImgSlider img")
.map(function()
     {
         return $(this).attr('src');
     });

var imgIndex = 0;
setInterval(function()
            {
                var url = imgs[imgIndex++ % imgs.length];
                $(".MiniModImgSlider")
                .css('background-image', 'url('+url+')');
            },1000);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu aqui.

Answer (score 1):

No metodo `.MAP()` você deve passar um parâmento antes de `function()` Com algumas informação,por exeplo o `alt`, como uma `array` com todas as informações que você deseja manipular.

De acordo com a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) do Jquery.

Ex:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var imgs = $(".MiniModImgSlider img").map(arr,function(){
    FAZ ALGUMA COISA
};
```